# How to apply filtering after serialization with Filter backend in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

For the context I will explain the current flow:
The model **Document** has a field document_signing_status which has 2 possible values: `SIGNED`/`NOT_SIGNED`. However, in the serializer, I override this field by having a custom `SerializerMethodField()` which applies some modification and instead of **returning 2 values it can return 4**: `"EXPIRED"`, `"WAITING_FOR_ME"`, `"WAITING_FOR_OTHERS"`, `"SIGNED"`

I don't want to store these values on the database level, but I need to apply filtering.

Right now I use filters. `FilterSet`, but it uses `QuerySet` so I can't simply specify filtering fields and pass "EXPIRED" since, in the model field there is only `"SIGNED"` or `"NOT_SIGNED"`.

How should I approach this issue? I thought about **iterating the query set and applying modifications for that field to have one from possible 4 options, instead of 2**, but not sure if it is a valid point and if even possible.

My `SerializerMethodField` (`DocumentParticipant` is an intermediate Many to Many model created with through)

```py
    def get_signer_signing_status(self, obj: Document):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        
        
        signer_event: DocumentParticipant = DocumentParticipant.objects.filter(document=obj, owner=user).first()
        
        if obj.document_signing_status == DocumentSigningStatus.SIGNED:
            return DocumentSigningStatus.SIGNED
        
        date: DocumentSigningDate = obj.document_signing_date
        # Expired
        if date is not None:
            end_date = date.end_date
            now_date = timezone.now()
            if end_date < now_date:
                return "EXPIRED"
        
        if obj.is_with_signers_order:
            if signer_event.order_of_signing == obj.current_signing_order_number:
                return "WAITING_FOR_ME"
            else:
                return "WAITING_FOR_OTHERS_IN_ORDER"
        
        if signer_event.participation_type == DocumentParticipationType.VIEWER:
            return "WAITING_FOR_OTHERS"
        
        elif signer_event.participation_type == DocumentParticipationType.SIGNER:
            if signer_event.signer_signing_status == DocumentSignerSigningStatus.SIGNED:
                return "WAITING_FOR_OTHERS"
            else:
                return "WAITING_FOR_ME"
```

Comment: Could you post your `SerializerMethodField`? My guess is that you have to write a custom filter method that mimics your `SerializerMethodField`, something like: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method

Comment: added, please check :) thanks, gonna read

Comment: Whats the problem of implementing these conditions on the database level and filter the queryset? You could filter for the data as well as the other conditions...

Comment: @BernhardVallant there is a problem, I won't go the details but it is not a solution.